# how can I update the new checked ones in the database in laravel

Tags: php, html, arrays, database, laravel

I can request the checked ones and view them but I **cant** update it.

in the database I have the table **types** and in types 2 colums: **rijbewijsnummer, rijbewijstype**

***how can I update the new checked ones in the database?***

functions in my controllers

```
public  function Modify (Request $request) {



   $user = Auth::user();
   $type = Type::all();

   $user->rijbewijsnummer = Request::input('rijbewijsnummer');
   $type->rijbewijstype = Request::input('rijbewijstype');




   $user->save();




   return redirect()->route('home');

   }
```

I think here i am doing something wrong

```
public function details(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $types = Type::where("rijbewijsnummer", "=", $user->rijbewijsnummer)->get();


    foreach ($types as $type)
    {



        $rijbewijstype[]= $type->rijbewijstype;



    }

    $user->save();






    return view('details', compact('user','rijbewijstype', 'types'));

}
```

view:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div name="rijbewijstype">
        <input  type="checkbox"  name="rijbewijstype[]" @foreach ($types as $type) @if ($type->rijbewijstype == "AM")) checked  @endif @endforeach value="AM" >AM</input>
        <input type="checkbox"  name="rijbewijstype[]" @foreach ($types as $type) @if ($type->rijbewijstype == "A1") checked @endif @endforeach value="A1">A1</input>
        <input type="checkbox"  name="rijbewijstype[]" @foreach ($types as $type) @if ($type->rijbewijstype == "A2") checked @endif @endforeach value="A2">A2</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rijbewijstype[]" @foreach ($types as $type) @if ($type->rijbewijstype == "A") checked @endif @endforeach value="A">A</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rijbewijstype[]" @foreach ($types as $type) @if ($type->rijbewijstype == "B1") checked @endif @endforeach value="B1">B1</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rijbewijstype[]" @foreach ($types as $type) @if ($type->rijbewijstype == "B") checked @endif @endforeach value="B">B</input> <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rijbewijstype[]" @foreach ($types as $type) @if ($type->rijbewijstype == "C1") checked @endif @endforeach value="C1">C1</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rijbewijstype[]" @foreach ($types as $type) @if ($type->rijbewijstype == "D1") checked @endif @endforeach value="D1">D1</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rijbewijstype[]" @foreach ($types as $type) @if($type->rijbewijstype == "D") checked @endif @endforeach value="D">D</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rijbewijstype[]" @foreach ($types as $type) @if ($type->rijbewijstype == "BE") checked @endif @endforeach value="BE">BE</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rijbewijstype[]" @foreach ($types as $type) @if ($type->rijbewijstype == "C1E") checked @endif @endforeach value="C1E">C1E</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rijbewijstype[]" @foreach ($types as $type) @if ($type->rijbewijstype == "CE") checked @endif @endforeach value="CE">CE</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rijbewijstype[]" @foreach ($types as $type) @if ($type->rijbewijstype == "D1E") checked @endif @endforeach value="D1E">D1E</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rijbewijstype[]" @foreach ($types as $type) @if ($type->rijbewijstype == "DE") checked @endif @endforeach value="DE">DE</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rijbewijstype[]" @foreach ($types as $type) @if ($type->rijbewijstype == "T") checked @endif @endforeach value="T">T</input>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, you're not saving your 'rijbewijsnummer' in the types table.

Long answer (using comments to explain the code and what it does):

```
 $user = Auth::user();
   $type = Type::all();

// Here you set the attribute rijbewijsnummer to the input value.
   $user->rijbewijsnummer = Request::input('rijbewijsnummer');

// Here you set the selected type as an attribute on the type object.
   $type->rijbewijstype = Request::input('rijbewijstype');

// Here you save the user (this means you can now get the rijbewijsnummer from the user table)
   $user->save();

// But you don't save the Type you selected, 
// let alone add the rijbewijsnummer to it, 
// so even if you did save it, you'd just get an empty rijbewijsnummer
// and rijbewijstype would be filled. 
// (or rather, overwrite the other empty rijbewijsnummer field with the new rijbewijstype, if you allow rijbewijsnummer to be empty)

   return redirect()->route('home');
```

You could fix this issue by changing the following line.

```
$type->rijbewijstype = Request::input('rijbewijstype');
```

to

```
// Creates a new entry in Types, using the rijbewijstype and rijbewijsnummer.
$type->create(['rijbewijstype' => Request::input('rijbewijstype'), 'rijbewijsnummer' => Request::input('rijbewijsnummer'));
```

I assume you wish to save multiple entries of the same rijbewijsnummer for the different types.

You also use some inefficient code and I don't think your database structure is as well thought out as it could be. But that's beyond the scope of this question.
Should your code be fully working you could always ask for help to improve your code on the Code Review Stack.